# Making a picture slide-show in Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere

I know using Premiere for slide shows is kind of overkill, but a lot of times I am working on a project with both videos and pictures, and it is much more convenient to use one program for everything.

Does anyone have any advice for any ways to automate any part of the slide show production (like the features in Windows Movie Maker or similar) within Premiere?

Answer (score 1):

For a slide show in Premiere the only recomendation that I have is that you set in Preferences > General > 'Still image default duration' to the amount of time that you want a image to appear, so you don't need to adjust after you drop them on time line.

Set the 'Video Transition Default Duration' to an appropriate time is also helpful.

And to finish, don't forget that Control + d (or Command + d on OSX) can be used to apply the default transition to the selected clip or image.